# MSSQL: running update usage after restoring database

Tags: sql-server

Why do we need to run `dbcc updateusage(0)` after restoring a SQL Server database on a different server? What are the implications of not running it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to run dbcc updateusage after you restore a database.  The only time that you need to run this DBCC statement is if the output from sp_spaceused isn't being reported correctly or if some of the reports in SSMS (or third party tools) aren't showing the space usage for the database correctly.

Comment: Thanks...So, after restoring, I will run sp_spaceused in source and destination just to confirm. This will save us a lot of time. Thanks heaps!

Comment: Even if the number isn't reported correctly this isn't a sign that there is a problem.  Depending on your version of SQL Server that you are moving from it may be normal that the number's reported aren't correct as older versions of SQL Server are well known for allowing the space used numbers to drift.  This has mostly been fixed in the newer versions of SQL Server.